# pyopencl and opencl on debian testing and fedora 20/21

Tags: python, debian, opencl, fedora, pyopencl

I'm trying to run a program that uses pyopencl on my laptop (with beignet). I used fedora 20 and installed pyopencl 2014.1 myself. That worked. Then I fedup'd my fedora to Alpha 21. Now the same pyopencl program doesn't work on the new fedora 21.

To debug the situation I installed debian testing on another partition on the same laptop. After installing pyopencl from the debian repository (no hand installing of any python library) the program that I'm working on runs as it did on fedora 20.

This is some of the error message I get. I tried to google parts of it, but have had no luck.

```
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'sample-profile-file' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'force-ssa-updater' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'loop-unswitch-threshold' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'unroll-runtime' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'unroll-allow-partial' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'unroll-count' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'unroll-threshold' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'max-reroll-increment' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'disable-licm-promotion' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'jump-threading-threshold' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'verify-indvars' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'max-recurse-depth' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'enable-load-pre' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'enable-pre' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'tsan-instrument-memintrinsics' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'tsan-instrument-atomics' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'tsan-instrument-func-entry-exit' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'tsan-instrument-memory-accesses' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'tsan-blacklist' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'msan-wrap-indirect-calls-fast' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'msan-wrap-indirect-calls' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'msan-blacklist' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'msan-dump-strict-instructions' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'msan-check-access-address' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'msan-store-clean-origin' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'msan-handle-icmp-exact' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'msan-handle-icmp' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'msan-poison-undef' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'msan-poison-stack-pattern' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'msan-poison-stack-with-call' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'msan-poison-stack' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'msan-keep-going' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'msan-track-origins' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'default-gcov-version' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'dfsan-debug-nonzero-labels' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'dfsan-args-abi' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'dfsan-abilist' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'dfsan-preserve-alignment' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'bounds-checking-single-trap' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-debug-max' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-debug-min' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-debug-func' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-debug-stack' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-debug' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-check-lifetime' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-opt-globals' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-opt-same-temp' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-opt' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-short-64bit-mapping-offset' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-mapping-offset-log' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-mapping-scale' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-keep-uninstrumented-functions' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-blacklist' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-realign-stack' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-memintrin' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-initialization-order' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-coverage' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-globals' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-use-after-return' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-stack' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-max-ins-per-bb' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-always-slow-path' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-instrument-atomics' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-instrument-writes' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-instrument-reads' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'ffunction-sections' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'fdata-sections' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'enable-double-float-shrink' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'slp-vectorize-hor-store' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'slp-vectorize-hor' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'slp-threshold' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'vectorizer-min-trip-count' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'enable-if-conversion' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'force-vector-unroll' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'force-vector-width' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'bb-vectorize-fast-dep' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'bb-vectorize-no-mem-op-boost' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'bb-vectorize-aligned-only' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'bb-vectorize-no-mem-ops' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'bb-vectorize-no-gep' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'bb-vectorize-no-cmp' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'bb-vectorize-no-select' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'bb-vectorize-no-fma' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'bb-vectorize-no-math' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'bb-vectorize-no-casts' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'bb-vectorize-no-pointers' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'bb-vectorize-no-floats' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'bb-vectorize-no-ints' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'bb-vectorize-no-bools' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'bb-vectorize-max-cycle-check-pairs' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'bb-vectorize-max-pairs-per-group' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'bb-vectorize-max-instr-per-group' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'bb-vectorize-pow2-len-only' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'bb-vectorize-max-iter' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'bb-vectorize-vector-bits' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'bb-vectorize-splat-breaks-chain' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'bb-vectorize-search-limit' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'bb-vectorize-use-chain-depth' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'bb-vectorize-req-chain-depth' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'bb-vectorize-ignore-target-info' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'error-reporting-is-cold' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'simplifycfg-hoist-cond-stores' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'simplifycfg-sink-common' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'simplifycfg-dup-ret' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'phi-node-folding-threshold' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'enable-correct-eh-support' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'unlikely-branch-weight' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'likely-branch-weight' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'enable-bc-uselist-preserve' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'max-cg-scc-iterations' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'enable-objc-arc-opts' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'fatal-assembler-warnings' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'reroll-loops' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'use-new-sroa' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'use-gvn-after-vectorization' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'vectorize-slp-aggressive' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'vectorize-slp' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'late-vectorize' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'vectorize-loops' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'internalize-public-api-list' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'internalize-public-api-file' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'inlinehint-threshold' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'inline-threshold' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'disable-debug-info-verifier' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'time-passes' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'print-after-all' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'print-before-all' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'print-after' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'print-before' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'debug-pass' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'verify-dom-info' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'info-output-file' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'track-memory' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'stats' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'view-background' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'version' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'print-all-options' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'print-options' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'help-hidden' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'help' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'help-list-hidden' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'help-list' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'enable-tbaa' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'verify-scev' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'scalar-evolution-max-iterations' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'verify-loop-info' defined more than once!
<premain>: CommandLine Error: Argument 'da-delinearize' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'sample-profile-file' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'force-ssa-updater' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'loop-unswitch-threshold' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'unroll-runtime' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'unroll-allow-partial' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'unroll-count' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'unroll-threshold' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'max-reroll-increment' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'disable-licm-promotion' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'jump-threading-threshold' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'verify-indvars' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'max-recurse-depth' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'enable-load-pre' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'enable-pre' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'tsan-instrument-memintrinsics' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'tsan-instrument-atomics' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'tsan-instrument-func-entry-exit' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'tsan-instrument-memory-accesses' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'tsan-blacklist' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'msan-wrap-indirect-calls-fast' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'msan-wrap-indirect-calls' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'msan-blacklist' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'msan-dump-strict-instructions' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'msan-check-access-address' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'msan-store-clean-origin' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'msan-handle-icmp-exact' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'msan-handle-icmp' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'msan-poison-undef' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'msan-poison-stack-pattern' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'msan-poison-stack-with-call' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'msan-poison-stack' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'msan-keep-going' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'msan-track-origins' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'default-gcov-version' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'dfsan-debug-nonzero-labels' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'dfsan-args-abi' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'dfsan-abilist' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'dfsan-preserve-alignment' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'bounds-checking-single-trap' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-debug-max' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-debug-min' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-debug-func' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-debug-stack' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-debug' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-check-lifetime' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-opt-globals' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-opt-same-temp' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-opt' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-short-64bit-mapping-offset' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-mapping-offset-log' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-mapping-scale' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-keep-uninstrumented-functions' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-blacklist' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-realign-stack' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-memintrin' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-initialization-order' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-coverage' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-globals' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-use-after-return' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-stack' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-max-ins-per-bb' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-always-slow-path' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-instrument-atomics' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-instrument-writes' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'asan-instrument-reads' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'ffunction-sections' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'fdata-sections' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'enable-double-float-shrink' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'slp-vectorize-hor-store' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'slp-vectorize-hor' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'slp-threshold' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'vectorizer-min-trip-count' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'enable-if-conversion' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'force-vector-unroll' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'force-vector-width' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'bb-vectorize-fast-dep' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'bb-vectorize-no-mem-op-boost' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'bb-vectorize-aligned-only' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'bb-vectorize-no-mem-ops' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'bb-vectorize-no-gep' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'bb-vectorize-no-cmp' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'bb-vectorize-no-select' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'bb-vectorize-no-fma' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'bb-vectorize-no-math' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'bb-vectorize-no-casts' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'bb-vectorize-no-pointers' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'bb-vectorize-no-floats' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'bb-vectorize-no-ints' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'bb-vectorize-no-bools' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'bb-vectorize-max-cycle-check-pairs' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'bb-vectorize-max-pairs-per-group' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'bb-vectorize-max-instr-per-group' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'bb-vectorize-pow2-len-only' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'bb-vectorize-max-iter' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'bb-vectorize-vector-bits' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'bb-vectorize-splat-breaks-chain' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'bb-vectorize-search-limit' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'bb-vectorize-use-chain-depth' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'bb-vectorize-req-chain-depth' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'bb-vectorize-ignore-target-info' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'error-reporting-is-cold' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'simplifycfg-hoist-cond-stores' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'simplifycfg-sink-common' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'simplifycfg-dup-ret' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'phi-node-folding-threshold' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'enable-correct-eh-support' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'unlikely-branch-weight' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'likely-branch-weight' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'enable-bc-uselist-preserve' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'max-cg-scc-iterations' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'enable-objc-arc-opts' defined more than once!
clang (LLVM option parsing): CommandLine Error: Argument 'fatal-assembler-warnings' defined more than once!
```

Can anyone point me in the direction of info on-line about this kind of problem? Ultimately I want to run my programs on fedora.

EDIT: Here's the program that I'm using to test opencl. It seems to me that the kernel's not being built.

```
import pyopencl as cl
import numpy
import sys
import time

class CL(object):
    def __init__(self, size=10):
        self.size = size
        self.ctx = cl.create_some_context()
        self.queue = cl.CommandQueue(self.ctx)

    def load_program(self):
        fstr="""
        __kernel void part1(__global float* a, __global float* b, __global float* c)
        {
            unsigned int i = get_global_id(0);

           c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
        }
         """
        self.program = cl.Program(self.ctx, fstr).build()

    def popCorn(self):
        mf = cl.mem_flags

        self.a = numpy.array(range(self.size), dtype=numpy.float32)
        self.b = numpy.array(range(self.size), dtype=numpy.float32)

        self.a_buf = cl.Buffer(self.ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR,
                               hostbuf=self.a)
        self.b_buf = cl.Buffer(self.ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR,
                               hostbuf=self.b)
        self.dest_buf = cl.Buffer(self.ctx, mf.WRITE_ONLY, self.b.nbytes)

    def execute(self):
        self.program.part1(self.queue, self.a.shape, None, self.a_buf, self.b_buf, self.dest_buf)
        c = numpy.empty_like(self.a)
        cl.enqueue_read_buffer(self.queue, self.dest_buf, c).wait()
        print ( "a", self.a)
        print ( "b", self.b)
        print ( "c", c )

def add(s=10) :
    starttime = time.clock()
    matrixmul = CL(s)
    matrixmul.load_program()
    matrixmul.popCorn()
    matrixmul.execute()
    endtime = time.clock()
    print s, endtime - starttime 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    add(1)
    add(2)
    add(3)
```

If anyone know's anything about this...

Comment: I think the issue here is that I had mesa-opencl installed at the same time. I think you *should* be able to have both installed at the same time, but at the moment you get the errors found here if you do. Maybe a time will come in the future where two opencl implementations can exist together on fc21.

Comment: BTW, I still get errors when I run the program above.